# How do I stop gyroscope-controlled camera from jittering when holding phone still?

Tags: unity, c#, gyroscope

I have here a simplified version of my gyro-controlled camera with a sensitivity modification (a side effect of increasing sensitivity is that the jitteriness is exacerbated).

```
public class GyroControl : MonoBehaviour{

private Transform _rawGyroRotation;
Vector3 gyroAdjust;
[SerializeField] private float _smoothing = 0.1f;

void Start()
{
    Input.gyro.enabled = true;
    Application.targetFrameRate = 60;

    _rawGyroRotation = new GameObject("GyroRaw").transform;
    _rawGyroRotation.position = transform.position;
    _rawGyroRotation.rotation = transform.rotation;

}

private void Update()
{
    _rawGyroRotation.rotation = Input.gyro.attitude;

    gyroAdjust = _rawGyroRotation.rotation.eulerAngles * 2; //increase rotation sensitivity
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(gyroAdjust);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, _rawGyroRotation.rotation, _smoothing);

}}
```

When in motion, the jittering isn't noticeable. But when you hold the phone still, there's what I assume to be just analogue noise that causes jittering. I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to add a filter or something to reduce the jittering for this kind of controller.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out Vector3.Lerp for smooth transition of values https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

Comment: Ok. Are you saying do Lerp instead of slerp? This controller I found online. I'm not experienced at  coding sorry.

Comment: Input.gyro.attitude is designed to give you a 1:1 match between the orientation of your phone and the orientation of the output quaternion. Multiplying its Euler angles by two is not geometrically meaningful and unlikely to achieve what you want. Can you explain to us what you're trying to achieve with this? How should your control scheme work, in detail? We may be able to suggest alternative ways to get that behaviour, without introducing jitter or other ugly artifacts of Euler angles.

Comment: @DMGregory I'm trying to achieve a first person shooter using the gyro as a camera. The code is a stripped down version of a controller I got from here: https://gist.github.com/kormyen/a1e3c144a30fc26393f14f09989f03e1 

As of now, everything controls fine with 1:1 orientation but I wanted to add a setting to allow increased sensitivity as it can get tiresome moving the phone around.

Comment: The multiplication is not present in that code. Can you clarify how you want your control scheme to differ from this working example?

Comment: @DMGregory I want to add an option to increase sensitivity to make it require less effort to aim. The way I multiple the Euler by 2 actually seems to give me the result I want just that it jitters while phone is still. The jittering also exists in the example code but it's not as noticeable. Somebody in the comments on that page said they fixed the jitter by "controlling the slerp" but they didn't say more than that.

Comment: @DMGregory Hi just bumping this. Do you know how I can fix my problem with gyro? Thanks.

Comment: @DMGregory  Been looking for solution and it seems the only way is to somehow filter out outlier data. Maybe have the transform delayed a certain number of frames (which would lag the movement) while I have something that is detecting a percentage pattern match on a previously recorded array of "jitter" frame transforms and removing that detected jitter from the applied transform.